# How do I create and fill XML with Key Value pairs with C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

I have an XML file that I am attempting to recreate upon selection in C#.The XML file will have some user selected info and data for the header that contains key : value pairs. How should I generate the XML and what do I operate on the XML with to have that format with a C# method?

I tried using `XmlWriter` but don't fully understand its use and how to format/write information with it.

```
<PULSE version="2.0">
    <TIME_STAMP value="" timezone="" />
    <CARD type="" version="" />
    <INFORMATION>
        <GENERAL key="" value="" />
    </INFORMATION>
    <DATA_PACKET time_offset="">
        <DATA key="1" value="1" />
        <DATA key="2" value="1" />
        <DATA key="3" value="0" />
    </DATA_PACKET>
    <DATA_PACKET time_offset="">
        <DATA key="1" value="1" />
        <DATA key="2" value="0" />
        <DATA key="3" value="0" />
    </DATA_PACKET>
</PULSE>`
```

I would like to create an XML of the same example format for use within C#.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using LINQ to XML rather than XmlWriter - the latter is a relatively low-level API. Start at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview

Comment: Yes, I second that. As you can see from my answer below, using the XmlWriter alone can become pretty tedious pretty quickly.

Comment: I never thought of taking that path. Any suggestions where to start with LINQ. @JonSkeet

Comment: You can create a class and add Attribute to point out its Properties are what XML elements: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes

Comment: LINQ to XML is an XML API, and I linked to a tutorial for it in the first comment.

Answer (score 1):

The basic use of XmlWriter is as follows:

```cs
using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(...))
{
    xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();

    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("PULSE");
    xmlWriter.WriteAttribute("version", "2.0");

    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("TIME_STAMP");
    xmlWriter.WriteAttribute("value", "");
    xmlWriter.WriteAttribute("timezone", "");
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

    // And so on ....

    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

    xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
}
```

This will create an XML like this:

```xml
<PULSE version="2.0">
    <TIME_STAMP value="" timezone="" />
</PULSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Using xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication120
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Pulse pulse = new Pulse();

            XElement xPulse = new XElement("PULSE", new object[] {
                new XAttribute("version",pulse.version),
                new XElement("TIME_STAMP", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("value", pulse.time.ToString()),
                    new XAttribute("timezone", pulse.timezone)
                }),
                new XElement("CARD", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("type", pulse.cardType),
                    new XAttribute("version", pulse.version)
                }),
                new XElement("INFORMATION", new object[] {
                    new XElement("GENERAL", new object[] {
                        new XAttribute("key", pulse.key),
                        new XAttribute("value", pulse.keyValue)
                    })
                }),
                pulse.data.Select(x => new XElement("DATA_PACKET", new object [] {
                    new XAttribute("time_offset", x.time.ToString()),
                    x.data.Select(y => new XElement("Data", new object[] {new XAttribute("key", y.Key), new XAttribute("value", y.Value)}))
                }))
            });

        }
    }
    public class Pulse
    {
        public DateTime time { get; set; }
        public string timezone { get; set; }
        public string cardType { get; set; }
        public string version { get; set; }
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string keyValue { get; set; }
        public List<Data> data { get;set;}
    }
    public class Data
    {
        public DateTime time { get; set; }
        public List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml = 
    new XElement("PULSE", new XAttribute("version", "2.0"),
        new XElement("TIME_STAMP", new XAttribute("value", "val"), new XAttribute("timezone", "val")),
        new XElement("CARD", new XAttribute("type", "val"), new XAttribute("version", "val")),
        new XElement("INFORMATION",
            new XElement("GENERAL", new XAttribute("key", "val"), new XAttribute("value", "val"))),
        new XElement("DATA_PACKET", new XAttribute("time_offset", "val"),
            from x in new Dictionary<string, string> {["1"] = "1", ["2"] = "2", ["3"] = "3" }
            select new XElement("DATA", new XAttribute("key", x.Key), new XAttribute("value", x.Value))));
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Country");
    XmlElement id = doc.CreateElement("Emp");
    id.SetAttribute("Name", "A");
    id.SetAttribute("Address", "Add1");
   root.AppendChild(id);
    doc.AppendChild(root);

    doc.Save("test.xml");
```

Comment: You should add a sentence of two explaining how your code answers OP's question. Code without comments is stale code.